# A-Frame: How to detect that the user has quit AR mode

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe

In the A-Frame project I have been developing, the user is first prompted whether or not they want to play the game in an AR mode or in a traditional non-AR 3D mode.

When the user unexpectedly exits AR mode (by pressing back and exiting fullscreen, for example), we need to be able to detect for this as we need to reconfigure the camera for traditional 3D again.

Is there an event in A-Frame we can subscribe to (or a property we can check) that is fired when the user exits AR mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the [exit-vr event](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/scene.html#events_exit_vr)